# Validating the following date format YYYYMMDD using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the input validation for the following date, but I'm not getting a valid reason.

I tried using month and date field using substring, but it's not working as expected

```
if (result == null || result == "") {
  alert("no value");
} else if (!newCheck(newDate)) {
  alert("Not a valid date");
} else {
  alert("valid date");
}

function newCheck(input) {
  var yearfield = input.substring(0, 4);
  var monthfield = input.substring(4, 6);

  var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield - 1, '01');

  if ((dayobj.getMonth() + 1 != monthfield) || (dayobj.getFullYear() != yearfield)) {
    alert("Month" + monthfield);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

My result to return true if the YYYYMMDD date is entered.

Comment: Java !== JavaScript

Comment: Please spend some time formatting your code properly before submitting your question.

Answer (score 0):

Bravo's answer will validate dates also, this answer will validate date format only. If you want to dates only with the `YYYMMDD` format use this code.
You can try this if date is in `20191010` then it will return 10th October 2019 date,

```
    let str = "20191010";

    let year = str.substring(0,4);
    let month = str.substring(4,6);
    let day = str.substring(6,8);

    if(str.length === 8 && (parseInt(month) <= 12 && parseInt(month) >=1) && (parseInt(day)<=31 && parseInt(day)>=1) && parseInt(year)){

        if( parseInt(month)=='02' && parseInt(day)<=29){
            console.log('valid');           
            let date = new Date(year,String(parseInt(month)-1),day);
            console.log(date);  
        }
        else{
            console.log('invalid date')
        }



    }
    else{
        console.log('invalid date');
    }
```

Comment: `parseInt(day)<=31` ... so 20190231 is valid?

Comment: Updated to handle above case

Comment: what about 20190431

Comment: also, 20190229 would be invalid

Comment: As per the question, he wants to validate the date format `YYYYMMDD`, not the date is valid or not.

Comment: 20190229 is not a valid date - validation should validate the data, not just a general idea of it

Answer (score 0):

The following works - the only `if` condition is if the original format is 8 digits or not - all other validation is essentially done by methods the Date object itself, because in javascript you can do "stupid" things `new Date(2019, 99, 99)` without causing exception

The validation of 8 digits is conditional on the constructed date being equal to the input date - `new Date(2019, 99, 99) === 2028-06-07T00:00:00.000Z` so therefore would fail validation since

```
2019-99-99T00:00:00.000Z !== 2028-06-07T00:00:00.000Z
```

```js
function validDateString(s) {
  const match = s.match(/^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)$/);
  if (match) {
    const [year, month, day] = match.slice(1);
    const iso = `${year}-${month}-${day}T00:00:00.000Z`;
    const date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day));
    return date.toISOString() === iso;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(validDateString('20200231'));
console.log(validDateString('20200228'));
console.log(validDateString('20209999'));
```

Answer (score -1):

could you please try this regex :

`^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$`

`var isValid = /^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?$/.test(inputField.value);`

Comment: Looks like your validating HHMMSS time not YYYYMMDD date

Answer (score -1):

You can use momentjs for that

```
if (!moment(dateEntered,'MM-DD-YYYY').isValid()) 
{ 
    console.log('Invalid Date'); 
} 
else 
{ 
    console.log('Valid Date');
}
```

https://codepen.io/jay3dec/pen/sKqeh/

> **For your scenario**

```
if (!moment(dateEntered,'YYYYMMDD').isValid()) 
{ 
    console.log('Invalid Date'); 
} 
else 
{ 
    console.log('Valid Date');
}
```

Comment: `dateEntered,'MM-DD-YYYY'` ... but the format is YYYYMMDD